# После 12 ночи выполнялось какое то действие

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать так в android,чтобы когда время после 12 ночи на телефоне, выполнялось какое либо действие

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/336120/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а я могу так SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH", Locale.getDefault());
    final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

Comment: if(strDate=="12"){ какое то действие}

Comment: что-то такое можно изобразить, но явно не так, как Вы сейчас написали =) Ваш код  будет выполнятся до посинения пока 12 часов не станет 13...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если вот так SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "HHmm", Locale.getDefault()); final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()); – danchik202020 22 минуты назад    
if(strDate=="1200"){ какое то действие}

Comment: используйте планировщик

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я прочитал не совсем понял как им пользоваться